# How to select lowest id from multiple id's on joined table

Tags: mysql

I have small trouble creating a query. I have two tables:

```
user_data
+----+---------+--------+
| id | mail    | etc... |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 | 1@m.com | ...    |
|  2 | 2@m.com | ...    |
|  3 | 3@m.com | ...    |
+----+---------+--------+
```

```
contracts
+----+---------+--------+
| id | user_id | etc... |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |       1 | ...    |
|  2 |       2 | ...    |
|  3 |       1 | ...    |
|  4 |       1 | ...    |
|  5 |       3 | ...    |
+----+---------+--------+
```

As you can see, the first table contains data about users and the secound one about their contracts. There will be always only one entry about a user, but a user can have multiple contracts. Now I need to find out 
all users, theirs **first** contract id *( with the lowest id in contracts table )* and their email, if it's in the were parameters.

So far I have such query:

```
SELECT
  u.id as user_id,
  c.id as first_contract_id,
  u.mail as email
FROM
  user_data u
JOIN
  contracts c ON u.id = c.user_id
WHERE
  u.mail
IN (
  '1@me.com',
  '2@me.com',
  '3@me.com'
);
```

Now I have no idea how I can select `only the lowest contract ID` from these results. Help apreciated.

Comment: Try selecting `MIN(c.id)` after joining the table? Or use `MIN()` as a condition when joining the table in.

Comment: This is a one time only select, so the performance is not that important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  u.id as user_id,
  min(c.id) as first_contract_id,
  u.Mail as email
FROM
  user_data u
JOIN
  contracts c ON u.id = c.user_id
WHERE
  u.mail IN ('1@me.com', '2@me.com', '3@me.com')
GROUP BY u.id
```

If you `group by` the user you can get the lowest contract by using `min`.

(And MySQL has no problem with selecting column that are not in a group)

Comment: Thanx, I new there was a simple way doing this ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    u.id as user_id, 
    c.id as first_contract_id, 
    u.Mail as email 
from users as u inner join
(
    select min(id) as id,user_id from contracts 
    group by user_id
) as c
on  u.id = c.user_id 
WHERE 
      u.mail 
    IN ( 
      '1@me.com', 
      '2@me.com', 
      '3@me.com' 
    );
```